# Как запустить тест с maven?

Tags: java, maven, юнит-тесты, test-automation, allure

Добрый день, пытаюсь запустить тест командой

> mvn clean test site

но maven выдаёт ошибку:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building TestWebDriver 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ TestWebDriver ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\eclipse-workspace\TestWebDriver\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ TestWebDri
ver ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1251 actually) to copy filtered resources,
i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) @ TestWebDriver
---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1251, i.e. b
uild is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\eclipse-workspace\TestWebDriver\target\clas
ses
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on
a JRE rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.138 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-16T16:53:53+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/114M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.
6.1:compile (default-compile) on project TestWebDriver: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on
a JRE rather than a JDK?
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
 [ERROR]
 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
 d the following articles:
 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureExc
eption
```

как я понимаю что ему нужна jdk но как на её указать в поме я прописывал адрес но появляется другая

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building TestWebDriver 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ TestWebDriver ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\eclipse-workspace\TestWebDriver\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ TestWebDri
 ver ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1251 actually) to copy filtered resources,
i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) @ TestWebDriver
---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1251, i.e. b
uild is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\eclipse-workspace\TestWebDriver\target\clas
ses
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.851 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-16T17:09:44+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/114M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.
6.1:compile (default-compile) on project TestWebDriver: Compilation failure -> [
Help 1]
  [ERROR]
  [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
 ch.
 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
 d the following articles:
  [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureExc
eption
```

Comment: У Вас ошибка компиляции видимо.

Comment: Как это можно исправить? Тест хорошо запускается из Eclipse но мне нужен по нему отчёт Allure.

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException тут сказано что ошибка может возникнуть из-за компиляции либо из-за плагина. Если тест хорошо запускается на Eclipse, тогда надо проверить плагин. Попробуйте другую версию плагина

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on
>   a JRE rather than a JDK?

Maven не может найти установленную версию jdk на локальном компьютере.

Попробуйте поменять переменную JAVA_HOME.

На Linux

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07/bin/java
```

В Windows через командную строку сделать (естественно поменять путь к своей java):

```
set JAVA_HOME="C:\Java\jdk7"
```

Альтернативный вариант на Windows

Взято отсюда -> https://www.java.com/ru/download/help/path.xml

**Windows 10 и Windows 8**

1. В строке "Поиск" выполните поиск: Система (Панель управления)
2. Нажмите на ссылку Дополнительные параметры системы.
3. Нажмите
   Переменные среды. В разделе Переменные среды выберите переменную
   среды PATH. Нажмите Изменить. Если переменной PATH не существует,
   нажмите Создать.
4. В окне Изменение системной переменной (или Новая
   системная переменная) укажите значение переменной среды PATH.
   Нажмите ОК. Закройте остальные открытые окна, нажимая ОК.
5. Откройте заново окно командной строки и выполните код java.